# Understanding "fields" returned by Node.js MySQL query

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysqljs

I've got a Node.js MySQL set up like this:

```js
db.query("SELECT * FROM build_stat",
    function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) { throw err; }
        fields.forEach(elem => {
            console.log(elem);
        })
        response.json({
            "result": result,
            "fields": fields
        });
    }
);
```

In the command line, `fields` prints objects like this. I believe this is ["Column Definition"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/page_protocol_com_query_response_text_resultset_column_definition.html).

```json
{
  catalog: "def",
  schema: "builds_stats",
  name: "recipe_name",
  orgName: "recipe_name",
  table: "recipes",
  orgTable: "recipes",
  characterSet: 224,
  encoding: "utf8",
  columnLength: 400,
  type: 253,
  flags: [ "NOT NULL" ],
  decimals: 0,
  typeName: "VAR_STRING"
}
```

But when I get it into JavaScript, the object has changed:

```json
{
    _buf: {
        type: "Buffer",
        data: Array(14600)
    },
    _clientEncoding: "utf8",
    _catalogLength: 3,
    _catalogStart: 3846,
    _schemaLength: 12,
    _schemaStart: 3850,
    _tableLength: 7,
    _tableStart: 3863,
    _orgTableLength: 7,
    _orgTableStart: 3871,
    _orgNameLength: 11,
    _orgNameStart: 3891,
    characterSet: 224,
    encoding: "utf8",
    name: "recipe_name",
    columnLength: 400,
    columnType: 253,
    type: 253,
    flags: 4097,
    decimals: 0
}
```

Why does it change? How do I preserve/regain the original object?

For example, presumably `flags: [ "NOT NULL" ]` corresponds to `flags: 4097`, but how do I parse `4097` back into something meaningful?

Comment: From [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#performing-queries)... _"fields will contain information about the returned results fields (if any)"_. It's not really clear what your question is though. What do you mean by _parse_?

Comment: This information is about the results of a query, not about the columns of a table (this query just happens to return table columns, but most queries aren't so simple). So it doesn't have table information like indexes. You can get that information from the tables in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

Comment: You can also perform the query `SHOW COLUMNS FROM build_stat` from JavaScript.

Comment: What do you mean by _"in the command line"_ and _"get it into JavaScript"_? Do you mean the difference between your `console.log()` and the response sent in `response.json()`?

Comment: @Phil, Yes, I suppose I mean the difference between what `console.log()` prints and and the response sent in `response.json()`

Comment: The big difference is the data sent in the response is run through `JSON.stringify()`. You might see more similar results if you use `console.log(JSON.stringify(elem, null, 2))`

Comment: Getting the nodejs file to print the latter object is easy. Accessing the former object with the more usefully laid out data is the hard part.